# Add Node to org.w3c.dom.NodeList

Tags: java, nodelist

How to add a node like

```
Element node = (Element) xpath.evaluate("//property[@value = 'entryDataTitle']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

to my org.w3c.dom.NodeList?

```
NodeList entryDataItem = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//item[@name='entryDataItem']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming that these nodes/elements all have the same parent document, if not let me know.)  I would get the parent node of that NodeList (entryDataItem) and use [appendChild:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29)

```
parentOfEntryDataItem.appendChild(node);
```

You might have to cast node as a node, not an element.  If you later need that NodeList, you can just say:

```
NodeList x = entryDataItem.getChildNodes();
```

Comment: Hi, there is no method called appendChild().

Comment: I've updated my answer with the link to the java API entry for appendChild().

Comment: Now I get what you mean. you want to say to use the object Node instead of NodesList. your code mentioned you using my entryDataItem which is of type [NodeList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)